# ¿Cuál es la palabra que quiere decir "cambio" y suena como "feria"?

Tags: coloquialismos, solicitud-de-término, méxico

Cuando quería yo comprar tamales en la calle, la vendedora no tuvo cambio exacto y me ha dicho que "no hay feria" o algo así. ¿Reconoce alguien la frase y ortografía correcta?

Comment: ¿En qué país te ocurrió esto? ¿México?

Comment: @fedorqui México

Answer (score 9):

Encontré la respuesta en el diccionario de la RAE:

> [**feria**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HlfHahn)
>
> 11. f. coloq. El Salv. y Méx. dinero (‖ moneda corriente).
> 12. f. Méx. y Nic. Dinero menudo, cambio.

Realmente yo debo buscar allí primero o en lugar de los otros diccionarios ingleses que yo uso.

Comment: De hecho también sale [en el Diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=hLQyqHw3Hx0Ar1GKWwp): _I. 1. f. Mx, Gu, Ho, ES, Ni. juv. Dinero suelto, cambio.
2. Mx, Gu. Dinero, moneda corriente. pop + cult → espon._